# multipartentity that seems to be multiple levels deep?

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, multipartform-data

I am having an issue with a client that is using some crazy (it likely isn't crazy, I really mean unfamiliar to myself ;) ) ruby rails plugin to handle the uploading of images with data attached. The way they say the server is looking for the information is

```
{
   "objectname"{
      "field"=>"value"
      "field"=>"value"
      "photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000004864fd0 @original_filename="avatar.png", @content_type="image/png", 
      @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"aPhoto\"; filename=\"avatar.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", 
      @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140211-8-1456165191981>
   }
}
```

the problem is that with MultiPartEntity (which is what they say to use) all I can do is get the server to see this

```
{
          "field"=>"value"
          "field"=>"value"
          "photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000004864fd0 @original_filename="avatar.png", @content_type="image/png", 
          @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"aPhoto\"; filename=\"avatar.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", 
          @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140211-8-1456165191981>
}
```

that extra layer of wrapping is proving difficult. here is how I have it, how can I achieve that extral layer under that key "objectname"?

```
MultipartEntity multiPartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.STRICT, null, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        ByteArrayBody imageByteArrayBody = new ByteArrayBody(imageBytes, "image/png", "avatar.png");
        FormBodyPart imageFormBodyPart = new FormBodyPart("photo", imageByteArrayBody);
        // sanity checks to make sure the headers are right
        imageFormBodyPart.addField("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"aPhoto\"");
        imageFormBodyPart.addField("name", "aPhoto");
        imageFormBodyPart.addField("filename", "avatar.png");
        imageFormBodyPart.addField("Content-Type", "image/png");
        // add the image body part to the multipart entity
        multiPartEntity.addPart(imageFormBodyPart);
        // add customer data
        Map<String, String> customerMap = user.getUserMap();
        // loop through the fields
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : customerMap.entrySet())
        {
            // create a new form part with the key as the name and the value as the value
            FormBodyPart body = new FormBodyPart(entry.getKey(), new StringBody(entry.getValue()));
            // sanity checking the headers are right
            body.addField("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"" + entry.getKey() + "\"");
            body.addField(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            // add the part to the multipart entity
            multiPartEntity.addPart(body);
        }

        postRequest.setEntity(multiPartEntity);
        postRequest.setHeader(KEY_AUTHORIZATION, VALUE_AUTHORIZATION);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of late. But I've stumbled upon a similar issue recently. The solution that worked for me is adjusting the code on the rails end to remove that extra param wrapping. As per my research nested parts are not possible with `MultipartEntity`